Interaction non related component interaction
Here I want to pass the data from the common filter service to page summary header where I am passing the data to the lastUpdatedTime in release-decision-component.ts file.
Filter service file:
lastUpdatedTime : String;

release-decision-component.ts file:
this.releaseManagementService.getGlobalConfigParameters().subscribe((tableData: ParametersData) => {
    this.filterService.lastUpdatedTime = tableData.createdAt;
})

page-summary-header.html file :
<cds-page-title 
    type="primary" 
    [pageTitle]="pageTitle" 
    [subTitle]="subTitle">
</cds-page-title>

page-summary-header.ts file:
this.subTitle = `${'releaseManagement.lastUpdated'}:${this.filterService.lastUpdatedTime}`;

Issue: When user comes to first time lastUpdatedTime is showing undefined. If I come once again it shows proper lastUpdatedTime.

Filter service file:
Uses BehaviorSubject to track lastUpdatedTime.
Provides an observable (lastUpdatedTime$) to emit time updates.
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class FilterService {
  private lastUpdatedTimeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  lastUpdatedTime$ = this.lastUpdatedTimeSubject.asObservable();

  setLastUpdatedTime(time: string) {
    this.lastUpdatedTimeSubject.next(time);
  }
}

Release Decision Component (release-decision-component.ts)
 Fetches global config parameters.
    Sets lastUpdatedTime in FilterService.
    
this.releaseManagementService.getGlobalConfigParameters().subscribe((tableData: ParametersData) => {
        this.filterService.setLastUpdatedTime(tableData.createdAt);
      });

Page Summary Header Component (page-summary-header.ts)
Subscribes to lastUpdatedTime$ to update subTitle dynamically.

 this.filterService.lastUpdatedTime$.subscribe(lastUpdatedTime => {
      this.subTitle = `releaseManagement.lastUpdated: ${setDateFormatForTable(lastUpdatedTime)}`;
    });

HTML Template (page-summary-header.html)
Binds pageTitle and subTitle to the component's properties


 <cds-page-title 
      type="primary" 
      [pageTitle]="pageTitle" 
      [subTitle]="subTitle">
    </cds-page-title>

